Why is Dragon Ball Z ep.179 "No More Rules," so much better animated than the others?
In Dragon Ball Z's Cell and Androids Saga, episode 179, "No More Rules," distinguishes itself as far better animated than any other in the saga, or any other in the series so far, for that matter.
One similar question on Reddit pointed to a list of episodes with the names of the director and animation supervisor, which seem to change regularly from one episode to the next.
Director Daisuke Nishio, who is credited for this episode, has directed many others in the series, and animation supervisor Keisuke Masunaga is credited by IMDb to have supervised two later episodes in the saga, without the same results.
IMDb also gives the air time of that episode as two weeks after the previous one, which is more than the usual week delay; however, other episodes have had more time before airing, like episodes 176 and 170, for instance, again without the same quality improvement.
So something must have happened then.

Did they have more staff that particular week?
Did they have more time for some reason, like starting way ahead of schedule?
Did they have some talented animators temporarily available at that particular time?

